# Async Callbacks Through Shared Message Queue

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I am creating a web game that connects via websockets.

It's easy enough to create a messaging system that handles calls in a websocket. The challenge is call response. "Request World Chunk 0,0" is easy enough. What I need is a way to distinguish message returns. I send a data request to the server, the next message I get back through the websocket could be anything: a player action, a score change, physics sync data, etc.

The best solution I can come up with is generate a UUID for the call, have that UUID be part of the return data, and then run the callback (or promise) for that UUID. (ie: `{request:'Get 0,0',id:'1234'}` `{response:DATA,id:'1234'}`). Then I need to track all those promises on the requester side, and manage some sort of timeout system.

I'm trying to find a better design pattern for this: A way to asynchronously callback through a single line of communication. Is there a better design for this than a callback ID system? Is there a Browser/Nodejs package that handles this easily already?

note: I mention websockets here, but I also expect a similar problem/solution for webworker elements: "create physics object", but the next message from the physics thread might be a collision message or renderer update message.

Comment: Callback ids work well, but require cooperation of the server. The other choice is filtering by response types. In either case you need some sort of queue for your promises.

Comment: Try to do it in a way that doesn't require this tight coupling between client and server? It sounds like it requires a lot of bookkeeping and lots of things can go wrong.

So you request a world chunk, at some point, the server returns a world chunk and that is processed by `world_chunk_processor`. Preferably this would even work idempotently.

Comment: I have complete control over the server. Decoupling is not necessary.

I believe the key based callback/promise is the best architecture here.

Thanks for the help.